# The FEP bend/wears out/scratching after 4-6 prints

Tags: resin

I recently run into some problems with my FEP on my Anycubic Mono X, but not in terms of failing off the prints, but rather in the really short lifespan of the sheet.

It frequently wears out and leaves clear dents of the prints behind, like in the photo.
The problem I mentioned repeated itself 3 times straight and happened similarly to one another.

The first prints are really nice and clear, but after some (2-3!) prints, the FEP is starting to get some dents from the previous prints.

The models I print after getting a light skin over them, which affects the quality and clearance of the prints and couldn't be washed away easily (even with a standard hand wash and/or a wash station).
Only with rubbing under hot water/IPA, but that's only possible with the larger surface models.

That wouldn't be much of a problem if the FEP were used to 20-30 prints like it is suggested, but in my case, the FEP gets useless after only 4-6 prints!

As the build plate gets cleaned too, I leveled it frequently after the instructions. Also, the lift speeds were different on the 3 FEP sheets I put on (at 240, 180, ~60 mm/min)

[image: Photo of an FEP sheet after few prints]

Answer (score 1):

I have an Elegoo Saturn, so my experience may be slightly different. I don't think that the lift or exposure settings will have an effect like you are suggesting, so you can probably ignore them as a red herring.

The first thing that I would do would be home the Z axis. It may be that it's trying to push the build plate past where your FEP is, rather than pushing against it and stopping. You may also want to double check your leveling method, you may be unwittingly doing something wrong. Though I think that this is the least likely of the two options.

Next I would check your slicer settings. I had problems with a skin forming on some of my prints and I eventually traced it back to two things.

One was me having supported several models individually and then combined the files together file that was corrupt but still printed.

The other was sometimes Chitubox would corrupt the raft at the bottom of the print. I noticed that if I zoomed in on the raft some parts of it would seem to overlap with each other or pass through each other. This also generated a skin when printing. I solved this by reducing or increasing the size of the raft so that different parts wouldn't intersect with each other (Some of my prints have really complicated outlines).

I also notice that you have some scuffing on your FEP, probably from cleaning, are you using paper towels to clean your FEP?

I was advised to stop using paper towels and instead to use either a microfiber cloth or to pour about 1mm of resin in the vat and then to use the auto clean function to solidify it.